# What could be a good translation of 'stable'?

Tags: traducción, sustantivos, solicitud-de-término

One of the meanings of [**stable**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stable) (as a noun) is:

> A group of people (such as athletes, writers, or performers) who work for or are trained by the same person, organization, or business

The translations I have found for stable in [Word Magic and Collins](http://www.wordmagicsoft.com/dictionary/en-es/stable.php), [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=stable#) and [Oxford](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/english-spanish/stable)  are '**establo**', **cuadra**, '**caballeriza**'.

I think they are not adequate. **What would be a good translation for *this specific* meaning of the noun 'stable'?**

Answer (score 3):

My two cents:

> **[equipo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=G09HIAP)**
>
> 1. m. Grupo de personas organizado para una investigación o servicio determinados.

But this is a very general word. For writers or performers you can also use:

> **[elenco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EWup5K1)**
>
> 2. m. Conjunto de actores que constituyen una compañía teatral o que actúan en una obra.
> 3. m. Conjunto de personas destacadas que trabajan en una misma tarea o constituyen un grupo o equipo.

A "stable of movie stars" would be thus translated as ***elenco de estrellas del cine***.

Comment: +1 por elenco, ¡no se me había ocurrido!

Comment: I have seen establo used for boxers, not for any other type of athletes

Answer (score 2):

I think it is hard to find a word in Spanish that can mean exactly this.

On a first thought, I would say...

> [**equipo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=G09HIAP)
>   1. m. Grupo de personas organizado para una investigación o servicio determinados.

But then I also like...

> [**cuadrilla**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BQ5Txes)
>   1. f. Grupo de personas reunidas para el desempeño de algunos oficios o para ciertos fines. Cuadrilla de albañiles, de malhechores.
>   2. f. pandilla (‖ grupo de amigos).

I included the 2nd definition (there are many) to indicate that *pandilla* would not match exactly, since it is a bit more informal.

Finally, I also like this one if you mean something more physical, like a group of people cleaning the streets or adjusting the lights on a neighbourhood:

> [**brigada**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=66BKqXj)
>   Del fr. brigade; cf. bergante y bregar.
>   1. f. Grupo organizado de personas reunido para un trabajo concreto. Brigada de trabajadores.

Comment: +1 although *cuadrilla* could be interpreted in the UK as the oil and gas mining firm [Cuadrilla](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuadrilla_Resources), if only by those affected by their drilling and those with current affairs awareness.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have also heard *cantera* used in this sense in Spain and the DRAE shows it as its third meaning [here](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7C9PGap)

> 3. f. Lugar, institución, etc., de procedencia de individuos especialmente dotados para una determinada actividad. *El equipo solo ficha jugadores de la cantera regional. Esta Facultad ha sido siempre una buena cantera de investigadores.*

Comment: I do recognise the usage of this word (specially in sports) but I am not very sure if it is a good match here. Probably because the noun _cantera_ refers to the place where they come from.

Comment: @fedorqui i see what you mean although I think it can be difficult to distinguish between the building and the people working in it.